# Unable to use owl carousel in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm trying to use owl carousel in laravel 5.6

I've included the following in the header and footer sections of the layout template

layouts/app.blade.php

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}">
    </head>

    <body>
    <script src="{{ asset("js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js") }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset("js/owlcarousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js") }}"></script>
   </body>
```

I have added the below in the welcome.blade.php

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
        });
    </script>
```

I do not see any slider. I see an error in the developer tools console that says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with bootstrap 4. However it works fine with bootstrap 4.1. Hence closing this question.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should link JQuery first like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: We can't wait for the rest of this answer ;-)

Comment: @Tom the answer was there all along - just some formatting needed.